# "authorization request has expired" when making OAuth authorization request

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

Our **OAuth PKCE authorization_grant** flow for our **External Application** w/our Banno partner was working fine for a few months, but now without any code changes to our OAuth flow, it has stopped working and  now throws the following execption.  The execption is thrown immediatly after we issue the initial authorization request to obtain an authorization code and returns a **Status 400**.

```
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "authorization request has expired",
  "request_id": "6c04e8395c7add20ef5393853dd31672"
}
```

Our authorizaiton request sanitized looks as follows, and has not changed since our initial working implementation:

```
https://[PARTNER-DOMAIN]/a/consumer/api/v0/oidc/auth?code_challenge=hffhU-4NMGxJ6-zF3x358EpvkUxSTnfXjzaQFGVIotM&code_challenge_method=S256&client_id=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXX-XXXXXXXXXXca&scope=openid%20email%20profile%20offline_access%20phone%20address%20&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://[OUR-1STPARTY-SUBDOMAIN].[PARTNER-DOMAIN]/auth/callback?channel=mobile&state=vwu8pg
```

We expect a redirect back to our provided **redirect_uri** with the auth code as a query param, but instead we get back a **Status 400** and the following response with what appears to be the auth code paramaterized instead of as a query parm:

https://[PARTNER-DOMAIN]/a/consumer/api/v0/oidc/auth/KZ_6Py3_T32lYHTlXXXXX

If I go back and run an the same PCKE auth flow through Digital Garden, the redirect comes back to the provided **redirect_uri=https://localhost:8080/dynamic** **correctly** with the auth code as a query param (`code=hSW62cciS817tQmK1cIIjtjG-Tmg0AHJGSolxe8KFdb`):

```
http://localhost:8080/dynamic?code=hSW62cciS817tQmK1cIIjtjG-Tmg0AHJGSolxe8KFdb&state=cabe7d6d9a2c55db777a2a164a1e5e8d755a2fcad537c08d79f0acee46e6816561c89fd95474f9f0bc38e47f45c4d524767f20ea0e313af6e9eefa8c
```

Basically, we can't figure out why we're not getting the proper redirect response as we were getting, and still do in Digital Garden to our authorization request.

I can also get the same exact error response trying to obtain the auth code using the same OAuth 2 flow from Postman **which doesn't involve any of our code** as show below:

[image: Postman OAuth Flow]

Error response:
[image]

Comment: There's a lot to unpack with the various errors which appear to be different. For the "client is invalid" case  with request id `33354714905bbc5456d46d7a5be8ffb8`, that error means that there isn't a valid client with the Client ID provided. It's possible that you have a typo in the Client ID (or the External Application was removed by the admin at the institution).

Comment: How realistic is the pattern for your redacted `XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXX-XXXXXXXXXXca` example Client ID? I notice that it is missing a character in the 3rd grouping and 4th grouping (which I marked in my notes with a (?) as `XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXX(?)-XXX(?)-XXXXXXXXXXca`).

Comment: Let me put up the correct Postman screen, I didn't realize I put the wrong screen up.  I am getting the same error in Postman.  Let me fix this  to avoid this confusion.

Comment: The correct Postman error screen is up now.  I have masked the client ID with XX's so, don't try and match them to a "real" client ID.

Comment: Clarification question: am I correct in understanding (with your corrected examples) that the auth flow _works_ in _Garden_ but _does not work_ in your _partner financial institution_?

Comment: Yes, Jamie, that is 100% correct.  And it was working at the partner institution for serveral weeks before we saw this error start to appear.

Comment: And there haven't been any code changes (or other configuration changes such as environment variables or deployments) for your software?

Comment: We look through our PR's since it was working and we don't see any direct code changes related to our PKCE flow.

Comment: I put our coded auth URL from our debug logs near the top of my question above(right below Status 400 error) if you want to check our payload.  I've looked at all the query params and all looks correct/complete to me.  We just don't see and attempt to go back to the supplied redirect-uri sent in the auth query param.

Comment: Engineeering thinks that something may be getting lost with the session. We'll circle back when we know more (or ask for more details).

Comment: So far it seems as though the institution has a _new_ URL, therefore the auth URL would need to be changed to match. You may _also_ have them change the Redirect URI as well, but that'll have to be coordinated with code changes for your plugin.

Comment: So, I updated the redirects to the new custom domain and authentication is WAI.   **To close out this issue, it was that the client had moved to a new secure custom domain for the auth flow, and we'd not followed suit.**  Once I switch to the new domain with new 1st party sub-domian URLs for our  service redirects, everyting worked perfectly.  I belive this query can be closed, but will leave open in case any more comments needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, the answer is that the financial institution had moved to a new domain but the auth URL hadn't been updated to use the new domain.

Using the example from the submitted question:

```
https://[PARTNER-DOMAIN]/a/consumer/api/v0/oidc/auth?code_challenge=hffhU-4NMGxJ6-zF3x358EpvkUxSTnfXjzaQFGVIotM&code_challenge_method=S256&client_id=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXX-XXXXXXXXXXca&scope=openid%20email%20profile%20offline_access%20phone%20address%20&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://[OUR-1STPARTY-SUBDOMAIN].[PARTNER-DOMAIN]/auth/callback?channel=mobile&state=vwu8pg
```

...that would have to be updated to use the *new* domain:

```
https://[NEW-PARTNER-DOMAIN]/a/consumer/api/v0/oidc/auth?code_challenge=hffhU-4NMGxJ6-zF3x358EpvkUxSTnfXjzaQFGVIotM&code_challenge_method=S256&client_id=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXX-XXXXXXXXXXca&scope=openid%20email%20profile%20offline_access%20phone%20address%20&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://[OUR-1STPARTY-SUBDOMAIN].[NEW-PARTNER-DOMAIN]/auth/callback?channel=mobile&state=vwu8pg
```